# Firebase C++ admob crash for android release build in cocos2dx 3.17

Tags: android, firebase, admob, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have configured Firebase Admob in cocos2dx 3.17 version. 
I will be able to see test ads when debug build. 
I have set the following dependancies.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
```

I have created an Android release build using android studio. 
When I launch a release build on the device, the application crashes. 
The crash log is as follows:

```
    04-11 19:01:50.358 1793-2283/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.7622 ] when=275481693441000
04-11 19:01:50.358 1793-2283/? D/InputReader: lastThreadEndTime = 275480391974048, currentThreadStartTime = 275480391978684, diff = 0
04-11 19:01:50.418 1793-2283/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=275481752767000
04-11 19:01:50.448 1793-2619/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{f7c7bdd token=Token{6fd63b4 ActivityRecord{e0a3887 u0 com.test.testAddApp/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity t7747}}} to stack=1 task=7747 at 0
04-11 19:01:50.448 1793-2056/? D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
04-11 19:01:50.458 1793-1962/? V/BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{cd84995 u0 com.sec.android.intent.action.HOME_PAUSE qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{2576782 25439:com.sec.android.widgetapp.activeapplicationwidget/u0a151}
04-11 19:01:50.528 25562-25562/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
04-11 19:01:50.578 1793-2283/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
    Device reconfigured: id=7, name='sec_touchscreen', size 720x1280, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
04-11 19:01:50.618 20509-20509/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 0 level=2 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f020655/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f020601 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_dark_2_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x0/(null) mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020655 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f02062c mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null)
    refreshSignalCluster : called
04-11 19:01:50.668 2733-2733/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU (Ia10634f51b)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
    Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
04-11 19:01:50.668 1793-1969/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:843 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:9078 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.access$2100:324 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:1263 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
04-11 19:01:50.708 25562-25562/? I/ActivityThread: Switching default density from 320 to 240
04-11 19:01:50.848 20509-20509/? D/StatusBar-QSPanel: onConfigurationChanged()
    newConfig diff : 480
    handleDelayedOnConfigurationChanged()
    adjustCellWidth mButtonWidth : 134, displayWidth : 1248
04-11 19:01:50.848 20509-20509/? D/StatusBar-QSPanel: adjustCellWidth mButtonWidth : 134, displayWidth : 1248
04-11 19:01:50.878 20509-20509/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 0 level=2 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f020655/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f020601 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_dark_2_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x0/(null) mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020655 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f02062c mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null)
    refreshSignalCluster : called
04-11 19:01:50.898 20509-20509/? D/SViewCoverView: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() : action : android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
04-11 19:01:50.978 25562-25577/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11210
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11210
04-11 19:01:50.978 25562-25577/? V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
04-11 19:01:51.008 24535-24569/? I/Finsky: [100091] hzb.run(3): Stats for Executor: BlockingExecutor ial@d7dd933[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 9]
04-11 19:01:51.008 24535-24569/? I/Finsky: [100091] hzb.run(3): Stats for Executor: LightweightExecutor ial@73534f0[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 61]
04-11 19:01:51.028 25562-25577/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000009e/n/armeabi-v7a
    ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000009e/n/armeabi
04-11 19:01:51.038 25562-25583/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 14711
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.test.testAddApp
04-11 19:01:51.108 20509-20509/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 0 level=2 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f020655/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f020603 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_dark_2_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x0/(null) mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020655 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f02062c mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null)
    refreshSignalCluster : called
04-11 19:01:51.318 25562-25562/? D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
04-11 19:01:51.398 25562-25562/? E/SRIB_DSS_ThreadedRenderer: initialize, mIsDcsEnabledApp=true , with format= -1 scaleFactor=0.75
04-11 19:01:51.398 25562-25562/? D/ThreadedRenderer: SRIB_DCS & DSS android_view_ThreadedRenderer_dcs_initialize Rendering in format=-1, factor=0.750000
04-11 19:01:51.398 25562-25590/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU (Ia10634f51b)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
    Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
04-11 19:01:51.478 1793-2672/? V/WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{6e0d7b9 u0 d0 p25562 SurfaceView}: mDrawState=READY_TO_SHOW
04-11 19:01:51.498 25562-25589/? D/cocos2d-x debug info: {
        cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x-3.17.1
        cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
        gl.supports_S3TC: false
        cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
        gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
        cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
        gl.renderer: Adreno (TM) 306
        gl.vendor: Qualcomm
        gl.version: OpenGL ES 3.0 V@140.0 AU@ (GIT@Ia10634f51b)
        gl.supports_ATITC: true
        gl.supports_ETC1: true
        gl.supports_OES_packed_depth_stencil: true
        gl.max_texture_units: 32
        gl.supports_PVRTC: false
        gl.max_texture_size: 4096
        gl.supports_NPOT: true
        gl.supports_OES_map_buffer: false
        gl.supports_OES_depth24: true
        gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: true
        gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
    }
04-11 19:01:51.528 25562-25589/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25589 (GLThread 100260)
04-11 19:01:51.618 1793-2893/? D/InputMethodManagerService: windowGainedFocus mCurrentFocusedUserId - 0 and mSecureKeypadEnabled-false
04-11 19:01:51.628 24535-24569/? I/Finsky: [100091] hzb.run(3): Stats for Executor: bgExecutor ial@968da69[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 23]
04-11 19:01:51.638 390-390/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a5ltedd/a5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/A500GXXU1CQB2:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '10'
    ABI: 'arm'
    **pid: 25562, tid: 25589, name: GLThread 100260  >>> com.test.testAddApp <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-11 19:01:51.698 390-390/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00044310  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
        #01 pc 00041f11  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
        #02 pc 0001ba13  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
        #03 pc 00018c81  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
        #04 pc 00016840  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
        #05 pc 0020552d  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so
        #06 pc 00205667  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so
        #07 pc 002057e1  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase9LogAssertEPKcz+36)
        #08 pc 00205f3d  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase4util15LookupMethodIdsEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassPKNS0_19MethodNameSignatureEjPP10_jmethodIDPKc+364)
        #09 pc 00218419  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase3app14CacheMethodIdsEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+68)
        #10 pc 00218e01  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase3App6CreateERKNS_10AppOptionsEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+512)
        #11 pc 001fb903  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN11AppDelegate29applicationDidFinishLaunchingEv+274)
        #12 pc 002458df  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN7cocos2d11Application3runEv+8)
        #13 pc 001fd38b  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit+198)
        #14 pc 007498d5  /data/app/com.test.testAddApp-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x57f000)**
04-11 19:01:52.118 20509-20509/? D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 0 level=2 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f020655/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f020601 mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_dark_2_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f0205ec mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x0/(null) mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020655 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f02062c mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null)
    refreshSignalCluster : called
    refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
04-11 19:01:52.248 390-390/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
    ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
    sys.mobilecare.preload = false
04-11 19:01:52.288 1793-25598/? W/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
        at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:981)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1390)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:4906)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:4583)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:5190)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18052)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17924)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:18701)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:18201)
        at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
04-11 19:01:52.298 338-338/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/25562/oom_score_adj; errno=22
04-11 19:01:52.358 1793-2056/? W/DisplayManagerService: Failed to notify process 25562 that displays changed, assuming it died.
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
        at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManagerCallback$Stub$Proxy.onDisplayEvent(IDisplayManagerCallback.java:81)
        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$CallbackRecord.notifyDisplayEventAsync(DisplayManagerService.java:1848)
        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.deliverDisplayEvent(DisplayManagerService.java:1632)
        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.access$500(DisplayManagerService.java:190)
        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$DisplayManagerHandler.handleMessage(DisplayManagerService.java:1776)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
04-11 19:01:52.358 1793-2283/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
    Device reconfigured: id=7, name='sec_touchscreen', size 720x1280, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
04-11 19:01:52.378 1793-25598/? E/WindowState: The process of this window already died: Window{6e0d7b9 u0 d0 p25562 SurfaceView} : android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
04-11 19:01:52.388 1793-25598/? E/WindowState: The process of this window already died: Window{c632203 u0 d0 p25562 com.test.testAddApp/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity} : android.os.DeadObjectException
04-11 19:01:52.388 1793-1969/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:843 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:9078 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.access$2100:324 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:1263 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
04-11 19:01:52.388 1793-25598/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
04-11 19:01:52.398 1793-2619/? D/InputMethodManagerService: windowGainedFocus mCurrentFocusedUserId - 0 and mSecureKeypadEnabled-false
04-11 19:01:52.418 1793-1818/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.test.testAddApp (pid 25562)(adj 1) has died(48,217)
```

Has anyone come across this issue for release build with Firebase admob?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by setting false to "minifyEnabled" and "shrinkResources" in module level build.gradle file :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }

            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                }
            }
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```